# Why Can I not display this span in chrome but I can in FF?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have the following CSS:

```
.views-imagematrix-block .views-field-title .field-content > a .promotedstar {
    position: relative;
    top: -6px;
}
.promotedstar {
    background: url("../img/icons/Star.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 25px;
}
```

And the following html:

```
<div class="views-field views-field-title">
    <span class="field-content"><a href="/content/gershwins-coffee-house"><span class="promotedstar"></span>&nbsp;Gershwins Coffee House</a></span>
</div>
```

This gives the full desired effect in Firefox, however in Chrome... It shows the span as being outside of the div (to the left), and doesn't show even with overflow: visible; set to the containing divs. (the span doesn't take the padding it seems). I don't know how to remedy this...

Comment: Could you make a http://jsfiddle.net/? It makes it easier for people to answer.

Comment: You are aware that width and height are not supposed to have an effect on a (non-replaced) inline element, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a Chrome bug. 
I think it relates to the fact that the SPAN is empty, I found in [chrome issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) some related bugs

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I filled it with &nbsp; and added display: inline-block; to css, and get rid of the padding form the CSS. It now works exactly as I would like in both browsers now, thanks.